# How to get ONLY unique values from list (delete duplicates)?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

If I have a list like such:

```
examList = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6]
```

How would I delete any of the duplicates from the list and only return the unique values to get the following list:

```
resultList =[3,4,5,6]  # [1,2] were deleted because they appeared more than once.
```

Essentially deleting not just the duplicate occurrences, but the duplicate number itself. I know you can use

```
set(examList)
```

or

```
is in
```

but those don't delete the duplicates number in general, just the duplicate occurrences.

Comment: The accepted answer in that question uses a lot of old stuff, like `dict.has_key`. A more modern approach: `import collections; counts = collections.Counter(examList) # get a dict of counts` then, `[x fo x in examList if counts[x] <= 1]`, although, to mimic that approach: `d = {}; for x in myList: d[x] = x in d;`

Comment: yeah, in general, *don't* do `[x for x in myList if myList.count(x) == 1]` That is O(N^2)

Comment: Why is that the "only viable solution" in the duplicate question?

Comment: Time complexity isn't always an issue. A simple solution with O(N^2) might be more preferable in some cases than a faster more complex solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try a list comprehension like this:

```
result = [item for item in examList if examList.count(itemm) == 1]
```

Comment: It's really worth noting when you suggest this kind of thing that order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: This isn't the result that OP is seeking. Elements occurring more than once should not appear in the resulting list at all.